# Bootstrap popover after shuffle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover, shuffle

I have divs with content:

```
<div class="mydiv">
<a class="mybutton btn btn-primary btn-small" rel="popover" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-content="some individual content"></a>
</div>
```

Popover work with this code

```
$(function () {
   $("a[rel=popover]").popover(); 
});
```

I need shuffle this divs, so I have this code

```
$('.jp-random').unbind('click');
$('.jp-random').click(function() {
  $(".mydivs .mydiv").shuffle();
});
```

After shuffle popover doesn't work.
**UPDATE:**
Ok, I'm updated bootstrap tooltips and popover code for version 2.3.1 and set data-container=".mydivs". Now my popover window in left top corner, how I can fix it?

Comment: Why do you need to unbind the click handler? and how does `shuffe()` work?

Comment: Could you please attach that to your question, using code formatting? this is a little hard to read.

Comment: http://yelotofu.com/labs/jquery/snippets/shuffle/jquery.shuffle.js this is shuffle function, unbind is from old code, sorry

Comment: No need to apologise, we just need to know some detail before we can be of help ;)

Comment: Any ideas about this problem?

Comment: By chance, i've been working on that same popover plugin not too long ago. see answer

Answer (score 0):

when you call `popover()` on a jquery object, it attaches listeners to that button.
`shuffle()` detaches it completely, also removing all attachted listeners.

This should be a simple matter of calling `popover()` again after you have shuffled the divs.